# Unable to unlock the version of a package installed via Scoop

Tags: scoop-installer

I deliberately installed an old version of a package:

```
scoop install podman-desktop@1.6.4
```

(as of today, the latest version is 1.7.0)

From now on, I want to use the latest version of the package, but it does not work.

```
scoop update podman-desktop
```

sticks to version 1.6.4, ignoring the newer version 1.7.0. Using option `-f` makes no improvement.

I can forcibly update to the latest version:

```
scoop install podman-desktop@1.7.0
```

But that's not what I want, because next time I want to update the package, the same issue will come up.

It looks like the only solution is to uninstall the package and then re-install it:

```
scoop uninstall podman-desktop
scoop install podman-desktop
```

But this makes me lose all the configuration I added.